# PHP8 подключение GD

Tags: php, gd

ОС Windows

Способы, которые не помогли:

1. Раскомментировать строчку "extension=gd" в php.ini
2. Написать строчку "extension php_gd.dll"
3. Скачать php_gd2.dll и поместить в ext (там не было изначально этого модуля). Затем в php.ini добавить "extension=php_gd2.dll".
4. Написать "extension=gd2"

phpinfo() не показывает, что библиотека подключена. При попытках использовать какие-нибудь функции GD появляется ошибка:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function

Если это имеет значение, то используется Web-сервер Apache2.4. В нём такие конфигурации:

```
PHPIniDir "путь\PHP" 
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
LoadModule php_module "путь\php8apache2_4.dll"
```

Comment: вообще там через знак = имена модулей пишут в ini

Comment: Извините, не так написал в вопросе. Но в php.ini стоит знак =

Comment: апач то перезапустили? вызовите phpinfo и убедитесь там что вы вообще правите нужный ini файл.

Comment: Поменяйте название файла на [php_gd.dll](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/gd2-gd-windows), аналогично и extension=gd. Убедитесь что это файл соответствует по архитектуре и мультипоточности (по необходимости и доступности). Запустите php -m для списка успешно загруженных расширений чтобы проверить что GD загрузился.